# Azure devops error Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 on port. Only local connections are allowed

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Azure devops error Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 on a port. Only local connections are allowed.
Unable to execute the build on azure devops. however, on the local system we are able to execute the exe.

I am using below function to return the path on azure devops

Code trials:

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase; 
// System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName ( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase); 
string actualPath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("bin") ); 
string driverPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath; 
driverPath = driverPath + "Driver"; return driverPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- Assuming you are using the current *chrome=71.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.45*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v70-72**

So there is a clear mismatch between  *ChromeDriver v2.36* and the *Chrome Browser v71.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v70-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.